# Nginx doesn't serve media files

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, nginx

I've deployed Django project using Nginx web server, but on the website, only static files are displaying correctly. When I try to access a particular media file using `website.com/media/file_name` it throws an error `Not found. The requested URL /media/dress.png was not found on this server.`

Here's my settings.py file

```
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
KEY_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'etc')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/


with open(os.path.join(KEY_DIR, 'secret_key.txt')) as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*',
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'endless_pagination',
    'catalog',
    'like',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bride.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR, ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'like.context_processors.like',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app_name.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'bride_db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/admin/web/website.com/public_html/app_name/media/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/'),
)
```

Nginx config file

```
server {
    listen      95.46.45.137:80;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    error_log  /var/log/httpd/domains/website.com.error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://95.46.45.137:8000;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pp
t|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mp
g|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
            root           /home/admin/web/website.com/public_html;
            access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/website.com.log combined;
            access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/website.com.bytes bytes;
            expires        max;
            try_files      $uri @fallback;
        }
    }

    location /static {
        alias   /home/admin/web/website.com/public_html/app_name/static/;
    }

    location /media {
        alow all;
        alias   /home/admin/web/website.com/public_html/app_name/media/;
    }


    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/website.com/document_errors/;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass      http://95.46.45.137:8000;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

    include /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.website.com.conf*;
}
```

I've already added all the necessary permissions for the `media` folder, so what can be done to show the media content from DB?

[UPD] I reloaded nginx and everything works fine now.

Comment: how about 'collectstatic' ?

Comment: @FeedTheWeb, I already used this command and the static files are loading correctly. Media files uploaded to DB don't display

Comment: Have you tried removing the "alow all;" in the location /media section?

Comment: @Phillip Watts, yes, it didn't help